# Autocompletion in texstudio : \frac

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I recently moved from Texmaker to TeXstudio, and there is one thing in autocompletion that I loved with Texmaker and which doesn't seem to work by default on TeXstudio : when I would begin to type `\frac` in Texmaker, it would autocomplete with `{}{}` and once I filled the first `{}`, pressing tab automatically moved to the second `{}`. This does not work by default on TeXstudio. Is there a a way to make it do that?

Comment: Use `ctrl+ right arrow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `CTRL + Right` will suffice under TeXstudio 2.6.6 (hg 4105+:b24377c712d7+) using Qt Version 4.8.5, compiled with Qt 4.8.5 R.

The manual says under section [`1.5 Configuring the autocompletion`](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION040):

> Use Placeholders: if the completed commands have options which need to
>   be filled out, "place holder" are put at this positions and they can
>   be jumped to by using `Ctrl+Right/Ctrl+Left`.

[image]

Comment: What is your TeXstudio version? My shortcuts to that are different.

Comment: @Sigur TeXstudio 2.6.6 (hg 4105+:b24377c712d7+), Using Qt Version 4.8.5, compiled with Qt 4.8.5 R

Comment: @Hal You are welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: @azetina, if you agree, please, accept my edit.

Comment: I don't like those shortcuts, since I use them to move one word left/right. Usually I use `alt` instead.

Comment: @Sigur Not quite! But what you can do is indicate your version to it. I will post an image right now with my version.

Comment: The image was taken with your shortcuts.